# How to compare version numbers in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to sort version numbers in an array, starting with the highest and descending to the lowest.

An example of the version numbers I'm trying to sort would be `W88.1.1`.

All I've really tried is:

```
$a = "W99.2.9", "W99.2.8", "W99.2.3", "W99.2.7" | Sort-Object -Descending
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried with so far ?

Comment: To be honest, I am somewhat new at PS and haven't been coding for long.

All I've really tried was:

$a = "W99.2.9", "W99.2.8", "W99.2.3", "W99.2.7" | Sort-Object -Descending

Comment: Can you tell us if the `W` leading the versions numbers is actually a reference to a version, example the version `W1.0.0` is newer than `V9.9.9`

Comment: No, it isn't. I could split the string, if needed to.

Sorry, should've clarified that from the start.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, question is mostly clear (I was just wondering what you mean by "Versions"), but anyway, refer to [mcve] and feel free to edit the post. 
I just briefly took a look around and you should to be able to use [Sort-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-6) function. But without any example or source data, without background, the proper solution is unreachable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you currently have the versions in an array, you can sort them like this.

```
$versionArray = ('W88.1.1','W88.1.0','W72.1.1','W89.2.1','Z89.2.1','A89.2.1')
$sortedArray = $versionArray | Sort
Write-Output $sortedArray
```

Output for this example will be:

```
A89.2.1
W72.1.1
W88.1.0
W88.1.1
W89.2.1
Z89.2.1
```

Add "-Descending" after the sort to invert the sort.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Although this works for the provided array of strings as soon as you have double digit versions sorting this way gets weird. Example: `@("A89.2.1","W72.1.1","W88.1.0","W88.1.1","W89.2.1","Z89.2.1", "W88.10.1", "W88.2.1") | sort` the version with 10 gets sorted between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 44):

The `[System.Version]` object type cast should do the trick:

```
PS  >  [System.Version]"2.7.0.19530" -gt [System.Version]"3.0.0.4080"
False
PS  >  [System.Version]"2.7.0.19530" -lt  [System.Version]"3.0.0.4080"
True
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work with variables though.

Comment: It will work with variables too

Comment: @RanadipDutta Their variable has W prepended which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: To handle the leading W, assuming 'W' is a fixed prefix and the numbers are a multi-part Version: strip leading W and covert to Version object, sort (descending), then convert back to string with leading W :  
$versionArray = @("W99.2.9", "W99.2.8", "W99.2.3", "W99.2.7");
$versionArray | ForEach-Object { [Version]$_.Substring(1) } | Sort-Object -Descending | ForEach-Object { "W" + $_ }